# Linq query for below data

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

```
id  vid Amount  Date
a   1   10  Today
a   1   5   Yesterday
b   2   6   Today
b   2   7   Yesterday
```

How to fetch records using linq where amount for today is greater than yesterday for each vid group bi Id and vid?

Comment: You mean a date is stored as a string `Yesterday`? If it's true, i don't know how to compare them.

Comment: Did you try? Share your code.

Comment: Nope, date is today's date or yesterday's in date time format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you have a class that looks like this:

```
class Data
{
    public string Id;
    public int Vid;
    public int Amount;
    public DateTime Date;
}
```

And an enumeration of instances of this class, which contains multiple instances that share the same `Vid` value, but different `Amount` and `Date` values. What you want is to get all instances which simultaneously have the greatest `Date` and `Amount` values of all other instances with the same `Vid`. Once you have that, you want to group the results by `Id` and `Vid`

In this case, you want the following query:

```
var myList = new List<Data>();
var result = myList.SelectMany(d1 => myList.Where(d2 => d2.Vid == d1.Vid && d1.Amount < d2.Amount && d1.Date < d2.Date)).OrderBy(data => data.Vid).ThenBy(data => data.Id).ToList();
```

What we are doing here is the following:

- Iterate through all elements in `myList`.

  - For each element, find all other elements with the same `Vid`, but a larger `Date` and `Amount`.
- Flatten all results into a single collection using `SelectMany`.
- Order the resulting enumeration by `Vid`, and then by `Id`.
- Convert the result into a list.

Comment: See if u look at the data, what i want, is to find out rows where amount for today is greater than amount of yesterday's for a particular vid. For the above data the result should be only first row

Comment: Exactly. That is what the query does.

Comment: Can I get the results as list<data>?

Comment: That doesn't work. Since the grouping anonymous type

Comment: ToList() will look for data class type

Comment: @SubhajitMondal Check the edited query. You can't use `GroupBy` and get a list result in this way. However, you can get the same result by using `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`.

Comment: do we have the similar thing in Sql server, how do I do the same query in Sql server